# Telling my MapActivity that my ItemizedOverlay has fired an event of interest. Design pattern?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

so I'm facing an issue here that I'm sure many a developer before me has faced as well.  I have my MapActivity class which creates an ItemizedOverlay class.  The ItemizedOverlay has a OnTap even.  When this OnTap event is fired I need to find a way to start an event in MapActivity class.  It's really quite simple.

So in More details I have:

```
public class Map extends MapActivity {
    private MapItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        itemizedOverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay();
    }
}
public class MapItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    public MapItemizedOverlay() {

    }
    @Override
    protected synchronized boolean onTap(int index) {
        // I need to find a way to tell the instantiating class this happened!
    }
}
```

I realize I can do things like use static variables, timers, and things like that, but they just don't seem like the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option #1: Make the `ItemizedOverlay` be an inner class of the `MapActivity`, in which case you just call a method.

Option #2: Pass the `MapActivity` into the `ItemizedOverlay` (constructor or setter), in which case you just call a method on the activity.

BTW, `onTap()` will be called on the main application thread, so it is unlikely that you will need `synchronized`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers CommonsWare. It seems that both options have their downsides. I'll probably go with option #2.